# Grabbing data from several tables and inserting into new table

Tags: mysql

I'd like to insert resulting data from the following statement as new rows in an existing table:

```
SELECT a.post_date, b.vendor_name, c.lastName, d.firstName, null as taxiGroup
FROM (select ID,post_date from wp_posts where post_type = 'shop_order') as a, 
(SELECT order_id,vendor_name FROM wp_wcpv_commissions) as b,
(SELECT post_id,meta_value as lastName  FROM wp_postmeta  where  meta_key ='_billing_last_name') as c, 
(SELECT post_id,meta_value as firstName FROM wp_postmeta WHERE  meta_key ='_billing_first_name') as d
WHERE a.ID = b.order_id and b.order_id=c.post_id and c.post_id = d.post_id;
```

But, if I use the form `INSERT INTO taxipassengers () VALUES(<the query above>);` I get `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6`, whatever that's supposed to mean.

Suggestions?

**Edit**: At first glance, that's a double quotation mark, but after I copy/pasted it here, I see that it's two consecutive single quotation marks, which is still curious but at least makes more sense since I don't have double quotes anywhere in my query.

Comment: What is the exact error. Please add

Comment: No problem, although the first part is pretty standard.

Comment: Tim, please check my answer below. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right syntax is:

```
insert into taxipassengers
select ...
```

So, there [is no values() clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html).

Comment: Thank you for your input! That would've been easy, but it's giving me the same error message: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6`

Comment: Pls copy the exact sql query you tried in the question, keeping to the formatting you have in your code. It is hard to fix sg I do not even see.

Comment: I tried `insert into taxipassengers (SELECT a.post_date, b.vendor_name, c.lastName, d.firstName, null as taxiGroup
    FROM (select ID,post_date from wp_posts where post_type = 'shop_order') a, 
    (SELECT order_id,vendor_name FROM wp_wcpv_commissions)  b,
    (SELECT post_id,meta_value as lastName  FROM wp_postmeta  where  meta_key ='_billing_last_name') c, 
    (SELECT post_id,meta_value as firstName FROM wp_postmeta WHERE  meta_key ='_billing_first_name') d
    WHERE a.ID = b.order_id and b.order_id=c.post_id and c.post_id = d.post_id;);`

Comment: Interestingly though, if I try it without the query in parentheses, I still get the error above, but it inserts the data as new rows anyway. I'm still curious why it's throwing the error, but hey, it works! So I'll take it. Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: Update: It was the semicolon(s). The final result w/o errors:

`INSERT INTO taxipassengers SELECT a.post_date, b.vendor_name, c.lastName, d.firstName, null as taxiGroup
    FROM (select ID,post_date from wp_posts where post_type = 'shop_order') a, 
    (SELECT order_id,vendor_name FROM wp_wcpv_commissions)  b,
    (SELECT post_id,meta_value as lastName  FROM wp_postmeta  where  meta_key ='_billing_last_name') c, 
    (SELECT post_id,meta_value as firstName FROM wp_postmeta WHERE  meta_key ='_billing_first_name') d
    WHERE a.ID = b.order_id and b.order_id=c.post_id and c.post_id = d.post_id`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, for aliasing we don't need "as"

```
SELECT a.post_date, b.vendor_name, c.lastName, d.firstName, null as taxiGroup
    FROM (select ID,post_date from wp_posts where post_type = 'shop_order') a, 
    (SELECT order_id,vendor_name FROM wp_wcpv_commissions)  b,
    (SELECT post_id,meta_value as lastName  FROM wp_postmeta  where  meta_key ='_billing_last_name') c, 
    (SELECT post_id,meta_value as firstName FROM wp_postmeta WHERE  meta_key ='_billing_first_name') d
    WHERE a.ID = b.order_id and b.order_id=c.post_id and c.post_id = d.post_id;
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! It's greatly appreciated. However, while that statement does work in and of itself (as did the originally inner query), when I try to insert the values from that query into a table using `INSERT INTO taxipassengers ();`, I get the same error message.

Comment: Try this, note the double brackets   INSERT INTO taxipassengers () VALUES((<the query above>));

Comment: Thank you for your help with this! It was actually the other direction - fewer parentheses and fewer semicolons. The final solution is in my last comment to the answer above.